# jquery width toggle animation is showing vertical cells during animation takes place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Please check this fiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/FvLQN/705/

Here you can see during animation, vertical cells are shown before expanding. I want to hide  that vertical cell instead I want expand div only in horizontal direction how to achieve that?

I know it is something related to css. Any help please

```
   animateFan = function() {
        $(grpFan).animate({width: 'toggle'});
        if($(grpSym).is(':visible')){
            $(grpSym).animate({width: 'toggle'});
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add these lines in your css..

#grpFan, #grpSym
{

```
/* Height of your sub blocks ...*/
height:44px;
overflow:hidden
```

}